# Cannot access view inside area in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am stuck in simple problem and i am not sure how to solve this.

> The view Category or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were 
>   searched:
>   ~/Views/ShoppingCart/Category.aspx
>   ~/Views/ShoppingCart/Category.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Category.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Category.ascx
>   ~/Views/ShoppingCart/Category.cshtml
>   ~/Views/ShoppingCart/Category.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Category.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Category.vbhtml

I have a area called ShoppingCartArea and i have view (Category.cshtml) and controller inside it. But i am not sure how it is referencing to main view folder.

Global.asax

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
          "Default", // Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "ShoppingCart", action = "Category", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
          );

  }

  protected void Application_Start()                          
  {
      AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
      RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
      RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  }
```

and my area registration.cs

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
     context.MapRoute(
         "ShoppingCartArea_default",
         "ShoppingCartArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         new { controller = "ShoppingCart", action = "Category", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { ShoppingCartAppMVC.Areas.ShoppingCartArea.Controllers}
     );
}
```

Lemme know if am doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you ran into this because you have added your areas manually. Recently I have been rebuilding old WebForms applications and slowly transforming it into MVC. I have not added MVC  type to a project and just added needed folders etc. Unfortunatelly, I`ve faced the same issue as you.

The answer was to add correct project type ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10546242/1300049)) and add areas from the 
context menu of the project. After that I`ve moved everything to a newly created area - and it worked.

So the answer is that MVC not only creates all the folders, but also updates its routes.